# How send push notification for all instances of application with Windows Azure?

Tags: javascript, android, azure, azure-storage

First, sorry my english!

I'm using a Mobile Service Azure, and have the Player and Mission tables. In the Player Table have a column that holds the RegistrationId each instance of my application. And every time we wanted to be insert into table in Mission, was sent a notification for my every instances.

my code:

```
// Function insert for Mission Table.

function insert(item, user, request) {
var sql = "SELECT registration FROM Player";
mssql.query(sql, {
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            sendNotification(results[i],'any text..');
        }
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("error is: " + err);
    }
});

request.execute();
}

function sendNotification(channel,text)
{
   push.gcm.send(channel, text, {
               success: function(response) {
                   console.log('Push notification sent: ', response);
            }, error: function(error) {
                   console.log('Error sending push notification: ', error);
            }
        });
 }
```